# which will cause cpu 99%ni?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading

Yesterday, I use top to see why my Quartz job stop running.

> And top show all cpus are with 99%ni?
>
> Which will cause cpu to change **nice** value so frequently?
>
> Can a dead loop in java lead to this?

Environment:

1. Linux kerner 2.6.18
2. JDK: Sun Java 1.6.0_23
3. Jboss AS 4.2.2.GA

[image: top result]

Comment: "Can a dead loop in java lead to this?" - yes.

Comment: @Stephen C why linux change the nice value if I had a dead loop?

Comment: @skjaidev  I don't know which will cause cpu to change nice value so frequently? that is my question.

Comment: Maybe your system is running something like the autonice daemon.  Or maybe the JVM was "niced" when it was launched. In this situation, the niceness is irrelevant.  It only matters if there is something else competing for CPU.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to the JVM with visual VM and profile the JVM. It may require special parameters at startup, but if you do this, you can connect to it and let the profiler tell you what is wrong the next time this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Take a thread dump of the java process - kill -3 pid  or jstack -l pid.  From that you can figure out which method is executing.  If you take multiple dumps over a period of time you can be certain if there is an infinite loop - the same method will show up in the top of the stack trace each time.